# How can I use an AutoHotkey message box with a timer when the Text of the message contains variables?

Tags: autohotkey

When debugging an AHK script I like to add MsgBox statements to help me know that a section of code was reached and I may want to include some variables in the message.  I'd like the message box to have a timeout so it self closes after 5 seconds.  I'd like to stick with the message box instead of using the ToolTip or relying on a function I would need to include in the script.

I'm looking for a *single line of code* so I can easily comment it out when it's not needed.

The problem I'm having is passing multiple variables to the MsgBox for the Text parameter is confusing it with the positioning of the Timeout parameter.  Is there another way of writing my variables so they are not interpreted as separate parameters?

```
WinGetPos, X, Y, W, H, A  ; "A" to get the active window's position.

; The timeout on this example does not work and the 5 is not shown.
MsgBox, 64, Debug, The active window is at %X%, %Y%, %W%, %H%, 5

; The timeout on this example works.  Is there a way to write this on one line?
msg=The active window is at %X%, %Y%, %W%, %H%
MsgBox, 64, Debug, %msg%, 5
```

[image]

Comment: Posting to Stack Overflow is like having a rubber duck.  In the process of trying to clearly explain what I'm really looking for, new terms come to mind that help my search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have commas in the text of your message you need to escape them with the backtick ` symbol.

```
MsgBox, 64, Debug, The active window is at %X%`, %Y%`, %W%`, %H%, 5
```

There are other characters that also need to be [escaped](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm).