# How can I use comma(,) in function like hotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to use comma in Hotkey function, but it is impossible as comma is used to script.

I tried {,} and {vkBEsc034} instead of , in my context

```
SendMode, Input
#InstallKeybdHook

hot>:
send, ^{F6}
return
hot<: 
send, ^+{F6}
return

!CapsLock::
+CapsLock
~CapsLock::
    {
        Hotkey, . , hot>, on
        Hotkey, , , hot<, on
    }

    KeyWait, CapsLock

    {
        Hotkey, . , hot>, off
        Hotkey, , , hot<, off
    }

    SetCapsLockState, off
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use literal commas, you need to add a ` before it.

```
Hotkey, `, , hot<, on
```

Comment: It's good to be familiar with [escape sequences](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm).  it will save you some frustration in the future.  I just had a similar [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57467419/1898524) happen to me.

Comment: It's really helpful! Thank you so much!